# So, about the swag

Tags: discussion, swag

We've been asked by the moderators of Worldbuilding to investigate the current status of official Worldbuilding SE swag, given that the site has a design. We've gone to check with the design team - unfortunately, there are currently no plans to work on site swag in the near future. We'd like to provide a clearer answer or even just how far down the road it might be, but it simply doesn't fit anywhere in priority amongst all the other design elements we have going on right now.

Comment: I'm disappointed by the news but appreciate you letting us know (hence upvoted).

Comment: Thanks for the update Grace

Comment: Possibly a silly question, but if the hold up is "our designers are too busy to put something together" would they be open to some pro bono help from outside designers? One of the original announcements suggested that it might be a t-shirt and notebook/moleskin with some of the design elements. Bother of those should be pretty easy to put together just using the SVG vector files used in the website design. It probably wouldn't take long. After that the hard part is getting swag printed and shipped out.

Comment: How about a Chinese bath salts manufacturer to brand the packaging with "World Building SE"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Worldbuilding entries for the swag contest on Meta](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6941/worldbuilding-entries-for-the-swag-contest-on-meta)

Comment: @gparyani, that's an entirely different swag