# Does someone have the source image of this site?

Tags: support, design

Where can I find the source image of WorldBuilding.SE? I mean this desert world, with the robot and the girl. If someone can help, it would be awesome.

Comment: You can get one version of it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSYWS.jpg).

Answer (score 5):

For the normal and meta design next to each other you can look at [Worldbuilding Site Design Updates: March 15](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3353/28789), which has the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXO1Z.png).

[image: main and meta design next to each other]

You can look at [Worldbuilding Site Design](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2916/worldbuilding-site-design), which has the link to an image that uses the non-flying-whales-city in the upper right hand corner together with robot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtSrG.jpg).

[image: WorldBuilding.SE design background image]

Comment: Man I want swag.  I need that as a poster in my office at home.

Comment: @James You need to be fast with such requests. Who knows how much of our design will stay the way it is with the [upcoming re-design](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6045/28789).

Comment: @James, apparently [there once was swag](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/worldbuilding-site-design-updates-march-15)... I feel so disappointed for not being part of the beta.

Comment: @JBH The swag was never shipped, even after people asked again [a year later](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5541/28789).

Comment: @Secespitus, that's heart breaking.

Answer (score 1):

But the flying whale?  Whither the flying whale??  Did someone feel the need to jazz this up with the addition of a flying whale?

Actually the whole city is different as depicted here.  This city has a spiral tower and a rocket.  On the main site there is some sort of a flying buttress and a flying whale.  What is up with that?  What are the chances that Robo and Green would assume this exact pose the same distance outside two different alien desert cities?

I want backstory.

[image]

Comment: You have a keen eye, interesting. The city matches on the meta site (in gray), but not on the main site. The robot is called [Slartibotfast](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3104/28789) by the way and the girl is called [Pandora/Alice](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3217/28789) or [May Suthers](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-brutal-builder-5fbfbad08c2a) as per your backstory request ;)

Comment: I updated the answer with a link to an image that has both the main and meta version as they are now. But thanks for pointing out that the other image was a combination of both of those. I couldn't find the individual ones though.

Comment: [We decided to mix up the two themes a little bit by creating a variation of the main characters for the meta theme and having a more gothic, steam-punk-inspired city in the main theme and using the futuristic city on Meta.](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3353/28)