# What is the worldbuilding background picture from?

Tags: discussion, design

Is it from a book or a movie or game?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  We're glad you could join us!  When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/welcome-to-worldbuilding-se?noredirect=1) to learn more about our culture and take our [tour].  You just received a crash course in the difference between our [meta site](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com) and our [main site](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com).  Meta is for "about the site" questions.

Answer (score 6):

The image in our site design is an original creation by Kurtis Beavers, a designer with Stack Exchange, seeded by ideas from our community.  You can see more about how the site design came about in [Worldbuilding Site Design](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2916/28) (there was a later [update](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3353/28) too), and in an [interview with Kurtis on our blog](https://medium.com/universe-factory/meeting-the-worldbuilding-designer-b5fde86de92b).

Comment: a _former_ designer...

Comment: It's heartbreaking the swag never came to be (and don't tell me it did, or I'll kick myself for not joining sooner....).

Comment: @JBH [it didn't](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5541/28), and I agree.