# Worldbuilding entries for the swag contest on Meta

Tags: discussion

If people didn't see it there is a [**swag contest on Meta right now**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318910/time-for-some-more-swag).  I thought we could collect links to all the WB entries and help each other out!

So.  Ill create a community wiki answer below where we can collect all our entries.

Don't forget to also vote for other entries you enjoy from users outside this community, though! Remember we're all supposed to be having fun here ;)

Comment: Does this count as a voting ring?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Nah, just supporting our community. ;)

Comment: Yes, please no voting rings.  Vote for stuff you like, don't vote for stuff you don't like, and look around at the other answers.  Nobody's going to see them all, but we should all look at some.

Answer (score 3):

Please provide your name and a link to your answer.

- James - [An epic ode to Worldbuiling](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319454/255733)
- Monica Cellio - [The problem with time travel: when am I?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/318963/162102)
- HDE 226868 - [A stopwatch for traveling near a black hole](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/318944/162102)
- AndyD273 - [A quick note from future me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319218/149126)
- Mithrandir24601 - [The Colour of Time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/318970/349720)
- Cort Ammon [Hack the future!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319221/232922)
- Victor Stafusa [Clock from the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319063/176034)
- Name